# Piping binary data in apache spark spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So I have an RDD of binary data I create it using

```
line = sc.binaryFiles("files/Videos",10)
line.map(lambda x:x[1]).pipe("cat").take(1)
```

I want to pipe this data to an external program but I get the following error

```
> Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 723, in pipe_objs
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 43: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Have any Idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us how you passed the data to an external program, but you probably want something along the lines of:

```
f.write(line.encode('utf8'))
```

You might prefer to have [io.open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#high-level-module-interface) create that file handle `f` for you, using a suitable `encoding=`, such as 'utf8'.

Do consider moving up from python2 to python3 -- you'll get clearer diagnostics about when there's a missing encode or decode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is how I pass my data:     line.map(lambda x:x[1]).map(lambda x:str(x)).pipe("cat").take(1)

Comment: I understand. I'm suggesting there's a missing `encode()` in that expression.

Comment: I used print line.map(lambda x:x[1]).map(lambda x:x.encode('utf8')).pipe("cat").take(1)     and i still get the same error

Comment: To debug it I recommend you break that expression apart so you have a simple variable assignment and a simple read() or write() call that reports the codec exception at position 43. You're looking for a compact "Repeat-By:" case at this point. And definitely consider using `io.open()`, perhaps under python3.